# How to fix "unable to unlink 'filename': Resource busy

Tags: git, git-reset

When I'm trying to revert some of my local changes it says "error: unable to unlink old 'filename': Resource busy"

I already tried to stash the changes, use `git reset --hard` but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried clearing .git/index.lock ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this one

Comment: If you're on Windows, it's because some Windows program has told the OS to hold the file for it. Git tries to remove the file (either to replace it with something, or just to remove it) and Windows says "no, I've held it for this other guy". Find out who the "other guy" (other program) is and make it stop.

Comment: Googling rather suggests this error at some Linux or Mac.

Comment: I'm working on Linux.I don't know how but the problem just dissepeard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to run the Editor (Ex: VS Code) with Administrator privilege and try again, it will work, I had the same issue and this solution fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by restarting my computer.